# Storm: Is it possible to limit the number of replays on fail (Anchoring)?

Tags: apache-storm

Is there an option to limit the number of replays when using anchoring?
I have a tuple that should parse json object, in case it gets an exception I prefer it will replay two more times.

I tried to track the number of times storm is replaying with prints, but each time I entered non parse-able value the counter showed different result.

```
catch{
collector.fail(tuple)
}
```

Comment: The spout should keep track how many times a tuple has been replayed. Maybe use a HashMap with key=tupleID and value=numberOfReplays.

Comment: Check ans on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912037/max-number-of-tuple-replays-on-storm-kafka-spout/53382783#53382783

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fail` method in the `BaseRichSpout` class is empty . meaning you are supposed to override the same method to handle the failed tuple reply strategy.

Comment: seems to be a good direction, I'm using kafka-spout.https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/blob/master/external/storm-kafka/src/jvm/storm/kafka/KafkaSpout.java, seems there implementation makes the infinite loop

Comment: as long as it does not receive acknowledgement for a tuple it tries to reply the same, making sure it process all your messages .. one of the key features offered by storm .. [more on this](https://storm.incubator.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html)

Comment: It looks like kafka-spout fail implementation is doing the replaying "infinity". After looking at the implementation, looks like they are using some parameter with 100K replays in default.

Answer (score 4):

Add a field to the tuple to hold the number of times to try again and use the tuple as both id and object on the spout's emit.  When the tuple fails, the spout gets the key (which is the tuple with the number of remaining retries) back and you can conditionally re-emit the tuple with the retry count decremented.