# 2 spouts one Storm Bolt

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I want to create a topology with 2 kafkaSpouts with 2 different topics and merge these 2 spouts into one stream based on sourceComponent in a bolt.

```
public class Topology {
private static final String topic1 = Real2
private static final String topic2 = Real1


public static void main(String[] args) throws AlreadyAliveException,
        InvalidTopologyException, IOException {

    BasicConfigurator.configure();

    String zookeeper_root = "";
    SpoutConfig kafkaConfig1 = new SpoutConfig(localhost:2181, topic1,
            zookeeper_root, "Real1KafkaSpout");

    SpoutConfig kafkaConfig2 = new SpoutConfig(localhost:2181, topic2,
            zookeeper_root, "Real2KafkaSpout");


    kafkaConfigRealTime.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
    kafkaConfigRealTime.forceFromStart = true;

    kafkaConfigHistorical.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(
            new StringScheme());
    kafkaConfigHistorical.forceFromStart = true;



    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout("Real1", new KafkaSpout(
            kafkaConfig1), 2);
    builder.setSpout("Real2", new KafkaSpout(
            kafkaConfig2), 2);

    builder.setBolt("StreamMerging", new StreamMergingBolt(), 2)
            .setNumTasks(2).shuffleGrouping("Real1")
            .shuffleGrouping("Real2");



    Config config = new Config();
    config.put("hdfs.config", yamlConf);

    config.setDebug(false);
    config.setMaxSpoutPending(10000);

    if (args.length == 0) {
        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();

        cluster.submitTopology("Topology", config,
                builder.createTopology());
        cluster.killTopology("Topology");
        cluster.shutdown();
    } else {

        StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], config,
                builder.createTopology());
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(6000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

In Bolt Execute Method I am doing

```
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
    String id = input.getSourceComponent();
    System.out.println("Stream Id in StreamMergingBolt is " + "---->" + id);

    }
```

So I want to store into separate files tuples coming from each stream
That is I want to store tuples for Real1KafkaSpout to file1 and Real2KafkaSpout to file2 . How can I do this I was struck at this point

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as follows:

```
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
    String id = input.getSourceComponent();
    if(id.equals("Real1")) {
        // store into file1
    } else {
        assert (id.equals("Real2");
        // store in file2
    }
}
```

You would open both files in `Bolt.open(...)`.

However, I am wondering why you want to do this using a single topology. If you only write data from Kafka source one into file one and data from Kafka source two into file two, you could simple create two topologies... (of course, you only program it once, and just configure it differently for both cases).

Comment: you are right.. but for my topology the tuples coming from 2 different source which need to be processed in bolts ... But before processing I need to store those tuples separately after that processing is same for the tuples from 2 source.. Data will be different but structure of data is same.

Answer (score 0):

Wired result when I am doing this by the following code

```
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
String id = input.getSourceComponent();
if(id.equals("Real1")) {
   String json = input.getString(0);
  //writetoHDFS1(json)
   } else {
      assert (id.equals("Real2");
    String json = input.getString(0);
 //writetoHDFS2(json)
  }
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wired results"? Or is it a typo and you meant "weird results"? What do you mean by "Above code works in most of the scenarios"? When does it not work? Why not?

Comment: @Matthias J. Sax But there are so many failed Tuples in the Topology ... How can I discard failed tuples..

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912037/max-number-of-tuple-replays-on-storm-kafka-spout